# The basic hello world kivy apk is more than 15MB, can I compress it?

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk

I have created and built a basic Hello World kivy app yesterday in Google Colab and build the apk using buildozer and the apk size was above 15.7 MB! Is it normal with the kivy apps or can I compress the app?
The code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class Main_App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MDLabel(text="Hello World", halign="center")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main_App().run()
```

The required in spec file:

```
kivy, kivymd, pillow
```

Comment: This might be a general issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464540/size-of-apk-when-coded-with-kivy-compared-to-the-one-in-java).

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing that can be done about this as a kivy app needs to package the entire python compiler along with the app. But unless you add any more big libraries like opencv, your apk size will most likely only increase by max 2 mb.